# android - How to set style for listadaptor

Tags: android, listadapter

I'm using a ListAdapter . When I run the emulator , the font-size of items are very big and I want to change the font size. I searched alot but I couldn't do much .
Here is the code :

```
String items[]={"a","b","c"};
```

Positions.this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(Positions.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items));

How can I change the fontsize of this ? 
by the way , is there anyway to typeface for the list ?

Thanks

Comment: use a custom item layout

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Custom List adapter for that

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a custom listview. In it, just change the line `android:textSize="22dp"` in the textview in `listview_item_row.xml` to whatever size you want

http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429

Answer (score 0):

define your ArrayAdapter like this:

```
    new ArrayAdapter(Positions.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items){
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View superView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            int textSize = 5;
            ((TextView)superView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, textSize);
            return superView;
        }
    };
```